# Is there a way to send receipt back to Firebase when user opens the push notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

On iOS, is there a way to know when the user opens a push notification from Firebase? When I go to the console, the send count is incremented, but the open count remains 0.

Comment: are you trying in real device or in simulator?

Comment: Where do you want this receipt to go? Do you want the other "client" to see that it has been opened?

Comment: @AlexL.Rocha I'm trying this on a physical iPhone.

Comment: @LarsonCarter Where do you want this receipt to go? - Just to the firebase dashboard for analytics purposes. Do you want the other "client" to see that it has been opened? - I'm not sure what the other client is.